# Does setInterval() function behaves like a thread?

Tags: javascript, html

Is the code in setInterval executes in parallel??

Comment: Try google and Try yourself before ask question

Comment: check link http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Please ask a proper question, what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. In javascript in the browser, unless you use [Web Workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker), there's just one thread.

Answer (score 0):

nope it is not behaving like a thread.

what happens is the following:

you execute stuff like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("bar");
}, 10);
console.log("foo");
```

it will add the function from that setTimeout argument into a queue, will execute the logging of "foo" and then will digg the queue for events that will happen next.

it will then execute `console.log("bar");`

internally it will look like:

```
console.log("foo");
// waiting for 10 ms unless another event is getting fired
console.log("bar");
```

this is extremely abstracted but basicly what happens.

what you search for are web workers as thejh answered already.

Comment: the `sleep` analogy is very poor - the answer would be better without it IMHO.

Comment: @Alnitak you are right. `sleep` sure is a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

It does not execute in parallel as you would expect from spinning off another thread, however it *is* asynchronous in the sense that the callback is not necessarily going to happen in a linear fashion.

How this affects you it's impossible for us to ascertain since you've not provided any meaningful information about your problem or why you want the answer to this question.